# How can I check how much space I am allowed to use on a linux server?

Tags: disk-usage, storage, quota

I have some giant files I'd like to back up by putting them on a server I am allowed to use for such things. However, I am uncertain about how much space I am allowed to use. Is there any way of checking this after I have sshed to said server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this quickly by trying to [create a file of the appropriate size](https://superuser.com/q/609020/151431). for example, to see if you are allowed to create a 20 GB file, create one:

```
truncate -s 20GB foo
```

This will create a 20GB file called `foo`. If you can do this with no problem, you know you are allowed to.

Comment: FSVO 'allowed' -- he might be *able* to create a big file, but he's not necessary *allowed* to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You could try `quota` if your sysadmin has set that up.  Also see the output of `df -h .` (straight after logging in) which will tell you how much disk space is available on the filesystem where your home directory resides.  Note however that this space is for the entire filesystem and not just for you.

Failing that, it'll just be an agreement between you and your sysadmin: I suggest that you ask him/her.